# Avoid showing android app chooser when source and target domains are same in http url

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking

I am working on adding support for http urls in my android app, but am facing a weird situation. I have an android app and a website and want both of these to support the same http urls. As a standard practice whenever a supported linked is clicked android shows the appChooser dialog to select an app to proceed (prior to Android M). This behaviour is fine when the user is coming from a different channel other than your own website. I do not want this appChooser dialog to be displayed if the user is already browsing my website on chrome and clicks on a link which is supported by app. Since he is already on my website on chrome I want him to go forward without any interruption.

Let me explain this with an example:
I have added support for http://www.mywebsite.com/xyz [1] in my android app
User opens http://www.mywebsite.com [2] on chrome then clicks on link [1] present on the page. In this case I want the chrome to load the url without showing the appChooser dialog.
Unfortunately, the default android behaviour looks to be showing the appChooser dialog irrespective from where the link is clicked.

Is there anyway I can achieve my desired behaviour?
I see that LinkedIn and Facebook have achieved this behaviour, but not able to figure out how.

Comment: Chrome won't let you choose an app when clicking a link with the same domain.

Comment: @Simon: I can see chrome throwing up a appChooser dialog even when the clicked link is within the same domain. For example: (with quora app installed) do this on the chrome - Quora > More > (Click) Blogs, you will the appChooser dialog

Comment: They are certainly using chrome intents https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: Looked through the html source (https://www.quora.com/more), they dont use chrome intents.. it is a default android/chrome behaviour to show the appChooser.. I am looking for a solution to override this behaviour when the link is within the same domain

Comment: Paste here the urll you're looking at the source please

Comment: I have figured out why linkedIn and FB are not facing this problem... essentially they bahave like SPA and dont reload the full document on link click.. they make an xhr request to fetch the content and fill in the dom.. so it is not a normal click and appChooser does not come

Comment: @PuneetPandey, I am facing the same issue with my app and msite. Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I dig into chromium source to figure out what is happening. As per chrome implementation when navigating within the same host it will show an Intent App Chooser if there is a newer App available to handle the target url as compared to the apps which can handle the source/referrer url. Source Code Link - https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/externalnav/ExternalNavigationHandler.java?q=browser_fallback_url&sq=package:chromium&l=385

Above explains the feature behavior that I am seeing. Since http://www.mywebsite.com is not handled by app, when user clicks on any link present on this page which is also handled by the app, it shows the app chooser.